# Is this function returning an unique value?

Tags: java

I'm newbie in Java. I see some people use this function to return unique id in Spring. Does This function return unique value?

```
public class Utils {
    private final Random RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
    private final String ALPHABET = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    private String generateRandomString(int length) {
        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            returnValue.append(ALPHABET.charAt(RANDOM.nextInt(ALPHABET.length())));
        }

        return new String(returnValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, obviously it does _not_ return a unique value. It simply returns a random string, just as the method name suggests.

Comment: i find google, and i think it is same hash function? Can i use this to generate user id in my program?

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not unique. It is random, but two random values can be identical. It happens. A better solution is to use the [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
return uuid.toString();
```

I can't resist linking to [Dilbert](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) here. Two random numbers can be the same!

Comment: Obligatory xkcd -  https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png